# Pass retrieved cursor from one MySQL database to another MySQL database using Python

Tags: python

Here is the situation:
I have one MySQL database that have a table called store_barcode with two columns: barcode, date. 
I have another MySQL database that have a table called product_info with four columns: barcode, product_code, product_desc, price.

My goal here is to first retrieve a barcode from store_barcode table and then find that barcode in the product_info table and print out the row for that barcode which will be the product_code, product_desc and price(to be stored in another table later)
How can I make such a connection?

Answer (score 0):

The first fetch the `barcode` row from `store_barcode` that you need. In the code below I'm just getting them all but you can use `WHERE` SQL statement to specify any needed condition. Then search the `product_info` table for the product with barcode you just got. Here's a sample:

```
import cursor


get_barcode_query = 'SELECT barcode FROM store_barcode;'
barcodes = cursor.execute(get_barcode_query).fetchall()

get_product_query = 'SELECT product_code, product_desc FROM product_info WHERE barcode=%s;'
for barcode in barcodes:
    print(cursor.execute(get_barcode_query % barcode).fetchone())
```

There you go, now you just printed all the rows with barcodes you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have a problem though. When I try to run: barcodes=cursor.execute(get_barcode_query).fetchall() I get an attribute error that None Type object has no attribute fetchall, the same goes for fetchone. If I don't call the method directly on cursor but rather first run cursor.execute(get_barcode_query) and then barcodes = cursor.fetchall() it does not give error but when it goes in the for loop it only prints None

Comment: Are you sure you have established a connection with your database?

Comment: Yes because if I don't put the condition with WHERE, it prints out the barcodes from the first query.

Comment: So the `WHERE` statement is the problem? You might want try it without double quotes, sorry for my mistake!

Comment: I tried it but still nothing, even simplified it by declaring a string variable called barcodes="2011111111095" (copied the number from database field) and then running the WHERE query and using fetchone() on the cursor but still it only prints None

Comment: I solved the issue, now it works. Thank you. Although there is another question I have posted, your advice will be appreciated.